# remove class from parent element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to remove class from a parent element, basically I have a `<audio>` tag (from now on referred to as `this`) which is inside a div with `class="playing"` how can I remove this class?

tried this, but than understood that it will remove class from audio element not it's parent div:

```
this.removeClass("playing");
```

Comment: Seriously, this is about as basic as you can get. Why don't you give just a tiny bit of effort, visit the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/), type in "parent" and see what comes up. Is that really too hard for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
this.parent().removeClass("playing");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).closest('div').removeClass("playing")
```

or

```
$(this).closest('div.playing').removeClass('playing')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.closest('div[class=playing]').removeClass("playing");
```

Answer (score 2):

JSfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dekajp/XSDrv/1/)

```
<div class="bold">
<p id="p1" class="blue under">Hello</p>
</div>
<div class="bold">
  <p  id="p2" class="blue under highlight">and</p>
</div>
  <p class="blue under">then</p>
  <p class="blue under">Goodbye</p>


$("#p1").parent().removeClass("bold");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input").keyup(function () {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('bg-red');
});
```

```css
.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.h-50 {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="h-5 bg-red">
  <h3>Add text inside input will remove "bg-red" class from parent div</h3>
  <input placeholder="Enter anything" type="text">
</div>
```